# ng-material-treetable custom headers

Tags: html, angular, typescript

recently i started using ng-material-treetable and run into a problem. i want to change header in another language could use some help.
this is example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnlruj

goal is to change header names into non English names()
[image]

Comment: Could you explain in details what your problem is ?

Comment: i would like to change table header name but cannot seem to find where to edit names(in image i edited it with inspect element to show what result should be). In mat table its in html <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th> like so. heres the original link to documentation of this material-treetable https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-treetable#data-format

Comment: I tried this solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmgd8v but not seems to work...

Comment: I went on the github repo of ng-material-treetable, and there isn't i18n support, worse you can't change the tree dynamically. I suggest you to fork the code in your project and adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Maybe you can try hacking the treetable component with '@ViewChild(TreetableComponent) treetable: TreetableComponent;' in your own component